# angular material table with row click and action buttons as a separate actions

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

I am looking for solution to support the row click and action as a separate function in the angular material table.

I have tried following:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-action-buttons-omoogj

I would like to achieve this functions:

1. on row click I would like to navigate to different detail URL page
2. on edit action click I would like to open different URL.

**Issue:**
I am not able to differentiate the row click vs the action items click as both falls in the same row.

Is there anyone found solutions for this or angular material supports this behavior?

[image]

**current behavior:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop the propagation of the event.

```
    <a mat-icon-button (click)="edit($event)">
        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>        
      </a>
```

```js
  edit(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('edit');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are looking for is [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Try implementing it like that:

```html
<a mat-icon-button (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</a>
```

By default click event bubbles through the DOM tree and is being fired on every layer.